How can i name a variable based on a file name?
I have a large number of .csv files full of data. For this type of data file I've written a Python function that reads the file and creates a datatable that has the information in a useful format. This allows me to create a datatable using the command
Datatable1 = DataReader("path/Data1.csv")

However, I now have to start reading a few thousand files like this, and would like to assign an appropriate variable name to each table. Such that, if a file is called "Data1.csv", I end up with a variable Data1 to which the datatable is assigned. How can I do this? This regards a few thousand files without a clear or consistent naming structure.
I run into trouble when trying to name a variable without directly writing the name of that variable in line, and have no idea how to do so.

Use a dictionary.

While this question might be similar to "How do I create variable variables?", none of the answers there seem to be a solution to the problem.

The solution is to use a dictionary and it's the first thing in a top voted answer.

The answer is: every newbie tries to create variable variables, and it's always wrong and an instinct you need to overcome. Use dictionaries.

Okay, thanks, I'll use a dictionary the way todeskurve suggested

i would go for a dictionary that would look something like this
Datatables = {}
Datatables['Data1.csv'] = DataReader("path/Data1.csv")

that way, you can easily iterate over all DataTables without having to keep track of all the different variable names. but you still can access each dictionary-entry via its name
if you really want the variable names directly representing the file i.e. Data1_csv, you can go the dark route and use the eval() Function

Don't use eval.

so "the dark route" wasn't clear enough?

Yeah, I think it wasn't (not my downvote though)

What problems might I encounter when using 'eval()'?

@JoelPeeters Check the link I provided. Insecure, slow, no way to debug it properly, just to name a few.

@todeskurve My initial comment was mostly meant to provide additional resource to explain why it is a "dark route", rather than any critique of your answer.

@matszwecja everything's good :-)
